# Redirecting Python Garbage Collection logs

Tags: python, logging, garbage-collection

By default on python, garbage collection logs are written to `sys.stderr`. Is there a way to redirect info level logs to `sys.stdout`? So that it's easy to differentiate between actual errors and info logs.

Comment: It looks like there isn't a way to customize where GC debugging messages are written, it's always stderr.

Comment: As GC logs gets written to stderr and other error logs(non GC logs) gets written to stderr, it  clutters the log file, So I was wondering if I can redirect GC logs.

Comment: I understand that. As I said, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: The documentation is quite clear, GC debugging messages are simply written to `sys.stderr`, with no way to redirect it.